# LINQ to XSD in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, xsd

how do I use Linq to XSD in VS2010. The last I know is to Install LINQtoXSD in VS2008 . Are there any updated in VS2010?.

Comment: This question was asked on the codeplex discussion board. Doesn't look like there has been any official development on LINQ to XSD for VS 2010.
http://linqtoxsd.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=235097

Comment: Check the [README.txt](https://linqtoxsd.svn.codeplex.com/svn/trunk/ReadMe.txt) from the SVN repository of the [LinqToXsd project on CodePlex](https://linqtoxsd.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The [current version](http://linqtoxsd.codeplex.com/) 2.x is for .net 4.0

[image]

There are **samples and docs** if you download the source.

Comment: How do I use this? any documentation. I dont see any.

Answer (score 1):

You could use command line:

```
LinqToXsd <schemaFile> [one or more schema files] [/fileName:<csFileName>.cs] [/lib:<assemblyName>] [/config:<configFileName>.xml] [/enableServiceReference] [/nameMangler2]
```

I do not know how to integrate it into Visual Studio 2010 since I've got only Express Edition.